# pnp differential input stage features

Tags: amplifier, bjt, differential

In one book I found that snippet. Can anyone explain me why the input may go below 0?

[image]

There is a text with that pic: "The limit here is one diode drop below
ground, at which point the base of Q3 will forward-bias against the substrate." Why one-diode drop is a limit? Why not two diode drops?

Comment: Explain _to_ you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need only an idea about that! I understand what Q1 emitter-to-base will be decreased by 0,7V and Q3 will be decreased too and can't understand why this PNP-stage need to drive with negative voltage but NPN don't!

Comment: A PNP transistor "opens" when the current flows **out of** the base. In this circuit, that happens at negative input voltages.

Comment: Some additional info added from book to picture

Comment: Think about an NPN with grounded emitter and a negative base. What is the base current and how does it vary with negative input current. Now look at the sample - what happens with varying negative inputs?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast With NPN with negative base the BJT will be closing with increasing negative base current. In sample - the BJT will be opening

Comment: @MaxMil - No. For negative base voltages, and NPN input (both the base/emitter and base/collector junctions) will be reverse biased, and conduct effectively zero current regardless of voltage - until you reach breakdown. Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember bipolar transistors can be thought of as two diodes, point to point in the case of a PNP.

[image]

So there is effectively a diode from ground up to each input. That will hold the input at one diode drop below ground if it is pulled negative...

Well.. till the diode burns out it will.

Comment: How to check if Q3 will be forward biased with one-diode voltage drop on input "in"?

Comment: @MaxMil Forward biased applies to diodes. When the input is at negative diode drop, both diodes are forward biased.

Answer (score 1):

Examine this diagram and the voltages very carefully

[image]

As you can see for **Vin** lower than **-0.6V Q3** and **Q1** are in the saturation region.